# Displaying special extended characters with PHP

Tags: php, special-characters, fontforge

So I've been working on this for a couple hours now and I'm close but I keep getting stuck on these special characters.

My client is a type foundry. The majority of their fonts have extended characters. The requirement is to upload 1 OTF file per each font, convert it to eot, woff, etc... then allow the font to be downloaded and purchased.

I've done all of this and I noticed when I do the conversion with fontforge, it creates an .afm file which appears to be an Adobe file.

After some poking and prodding, this AFM file contains a list of all characters in the font. Awesome!

Now I'm trying to embed the OTF file in the page to display all the characters it comes with and I can't figure out which character encoding to use.

A sample of my AFM file:

```
C 251 ; WX 965 ; N ucircumflex ; B 90 -10 869 691 ;
C 252 ; WX 965 ; N udieresis ; B 90 -10 869 675 ;
C 253 ; WX 856 ; N yacute ; B 11 -182 845 678 ;
C 254 ; WX 947 ; N thorn ; B 96 -172 899 668 ;
C 255 ; WX 856 ; N ydieresis ; B 11 -182 845 675 ;
C -1 ; WX 1090 ; N Amacron ; B 0 0 1090 820 ;
C -1 ; WX 927 ; N amacron ; B 65 0 861 655 ;
C -1 ; WX 1090 ; N Abreve ; B 0 0 1090 851 ;
C -1 ; WX 927 ; N abreve ; B 65 0 861 686 ;
C -1 ; WX 1090 ; N Aogonek ; B 0 -182 1090 668 ;
C -1 ; WX 927 ; N aogonek ; B 65 -182 861 496 ;
C -1 ; WX 1093 ; N Cacute ; B 63 -10 1040 843 ;
C -1 ; WX 917 ; N cacute ; B 48 -10 883 678 ;
```

And how I'm trying to display the characters with PHP

```
if($row['afm'])
{
    $in = 0;
    $file_handle = fopen($row['afm'], "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) 
    {
        $line = fgets($file_handle);
        if(substr($line, 0, 16) == "StartCharMetrics")
        {
            $in = 1;
        }

        if(substr($line, 0, 14) == "EndCharMetrics")
        {
            $in = 0;
        }

        if($in == 1)
        {
            list($c, $wx, $n, $b) = explode(";", $line);
            list($a, $b) = explode(" ", trim($c));
            echo "<div class='box' style='font-family: sample; width: 150px; height: 50px; border: 1px #c4c4c4 solid; float: left; padding: 10px; font-family: sample; font-size: 44px;'>";
            //echo $b . "<br>";
            if($b == "-1")
            {
                list($nn, $nnn) = explode(" ", trim($n));
                //echo "<!ENTITY " . $nnn . " \&" . $nnn . ";>";
                echo unichr($nnn);
                //echo htmlspecialchars_decode("&" . $nnn . ";");
            }
            else
            {
                echo unichr($b);
            }
    //      echo $line . "<br>";
            echo "</div>";

        }

    }
    fclose($file_handle);
}
function unichr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML_ENTITIES');
}
```

If $c contains a recognized character (ie: not -1) use that, otherwise, use whats in $n - its the $n I can't get to display properly - characters like "aogonek"

I've tried UTF-8 in the meta and header, various ISO formats, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out!

I remember seeing that fontforge can also export an SVG file. On a wim, I converted the OTF file to SVG and opened it in a text editor - its plain human readable text that looks like

```
<glyph glyph-name="ff" unicode="ff" horiz-adv-x="1001" 
d="M26 496h74v58c0 67 56 114 139 114h267v-131h-101c-25 0 -37 -13 -37 -41h85v-135h-85v-361h-268v361h-74v135zM512 496h74v58c0 67 56 114 139 114h267v-131h-101c-25 0 -37 -13 -37 -41h85v-135h-85v-361h-268v361h-74v135z" />
```

After I saw that, it was a matter of using [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and echoing the unicode character from the line.

Comment: Fontforge can generate Unified Font Object file format. An UFO is a directory representing font data with one or more glyph layers. And could be ideal for your task. http://unifiedfontobject.org/